# dplyr tidyr spread error in column names and input

Tags: r, layout, dplyr, tidyr, spread

I am trying to perform the `spread` function from `tidyr` on a dataset with Destination and Origin Names for plane journeys and their number of passengers. I try to build a table that could eventually be used for a heatmap. Hence, I want to have the Origin variable in the rows and the Destination variable as the columns.

I tried to run the code with different combinations of argument and also using the `spread_` but I always end up with errors.

If I use the `spread_` with  `key_col` and `val_col` , I get:

> Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
>     object 'Destination.Region' not found

On my large dataset, It produces another type of error :

> Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("ASIA SUB-CONTINENT", "AUSTRALIA",  : 
>     length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

It is the first time I am using `tidyr` and I am getting to know the packages, which does not sounds too complicated. But I have been working on that problem since few hours and couldn't find any answer on any forums.

Thanks for the help,

Here is an example of the type of data:

```
data2<-matrix(NA, nrow = 7, ncol=3)  
colnames(data2)<-c("Origin.Destination", "Total.Passengers", "Destination.Region")
data2[,1] <- c("EAST AFRICA","SOUTHERN AFRICA","WEST AFRICA", "EAST AFRICA", "SOUTHERN AFRICA", "EAST AFRICA","EAST AFRICA")
data2[,2] <- c(100, 5000, 200, 10000, 200, 20, 4000)
data2[,3] <- c("WESTERN EUROPE", "SOUTH AMERICA", "ASIA", "SOUTH AMERICA", "ASIA", "WESTERN EUROPE", "WESTERN EUROPE")
```

data2<-data.frame(data2)

And here is my code:

```
DF<- 
  data2 %>%
  spread_(key_ = "Destination.Region",
     value_ = "Total.Passengers", 
     convert = TRUE,
     drop = FALSE)
```

Comment: `Total.Passengers` versus `Passengers`?

Comment: That is a typing error in my question. I just corrected it. Still got a problem with my code though. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Your example data also seems like you've mislabelled the columns in other ways. Why don't you fix your example completely first?

Comment: I see, I fixed it as well. Thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce either error message with your example dataset.  I get the standard "duplicate identifiers" error, and if I remove the duplicate identifiers `spread` works without error.  You might update your example to make it more like your actual dataset or include the structure (from `str(data2)`) of your real data if it is too big to `dput`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things to try:

1) I would convert `data2` to a `data.frame`. It makes working with it a lot easier.

```
data2<-matrix(NA, nrow = 7, ncol=3)  
colnames(data2)<-c("Origin.Destination", "Total.Passengers", "Destination.Region")
data2[,1] <- c("EAST AFRICA","SOUTHERN AFRICA","WEST AFRICA", "EAST AFRICA", "SOUTHERN AFRICA", "EAST AFRICA","EAST AFRICA")
data2[,2] <- c(100, 5000, 200, 10000, 200, 20, 4000)
data2[,3] <- c("WESTERN EUROPE", "SOUTH AMERICA", "ASIA", "SOUTH AMERICA", "ASIA", "WESTERN EUROPE", "WESTERN EUROPE")

data3<-data.frame(data2)
```

2) The new `data.frame` will need an unambiguous column (usually an index column) to make the `spread_` function work properly. Otherwise:

```
DF<- 
  data3 %>%
  spread_(key_ = "Destination.Region",
          value_ = "Total.Passengers", 
          convert = TRUE,
          drop = FALSE)

Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows (1, 6, 7)
```

But if:

```
data3$index<-1:nrow(data3)

DF<- 
  data3 %>%
  spread_(key_ = "Destination.Region",
          value_ = "Total.Passengers", 
          convert = TRUE,
          drop = FALSE)
DF

Origin.Destination index ASIA SOUTH AMERICA WESTERN EUROPE
1         EAST AFRICA     1   NA            NA            100
2         EAST AFRICA     2   NA            NA             NA
3         EAST AFRICA     3   NA            NA             NA
4         EAST AFRICA     4   NA         10000             NA
5         EAST AFRICA     5   NA            NA             NA
6         EAST AFRICA     6   NA            NA             20
7         EAST AFRICA     7   NA            NA           4000
8     SOUTHERN AFRICA     1   NA            NA             NA
9     SOUTHERN AFRICA     2   NA          5000             NA
10    SOUTHERN AFRICA     3   NA            NA             NA
11    SOUTHERN AFRICA     4   NA            NA             NA
12    SOUTHERN AFRICA     5  200            NA             NA
13    SOUTHERN AFRICA     6   NA            NA             NA
14    SOUTHERN AFRICA     7   NA            NA             NA
15        WEST AFRICA     1   NA            NA             NA
16        WEST AFRICA     2   NA            NA             NA
17        WEST AFRICA     3  200            NA             NA
18        WEST AFRICA     4   NA            NA             NA
19        WEST AFRICA     5   NA            NA             NA
20        WEST AFRICA     6   NA            NA             NA
21        WEST AFRICA     7   NA            NA             NA
```

One thing that might make sense here would be to `sum` the total passengers by origin and destination. That would avoid the use of indexes and prevent so many NAs:

```
Origin <- c("EAST AFRICA","SOUTHERN AFRICA","WEST AFRICA", "EAST AFRICA", "SOUTHERN AFRICA", "EAST AFRICA","EAST AFRICA")
Passengers <- c(100, 5000, 200, 10000, 200, 20, 4000)
Destination <- c("WESTERN EUROPE", "SOUTH AMERICA", "ASIA", "SOUTH AMERICA", "ASIA", "WESTERN EUROPE", "WESTERN EUROPE")
data3<-data.frame(Origin, Passengers, Destination)

DF<-data3 %>% group_by(Origin, Destination) %>%
  summarise(Total.Passengers = sum(Passengers)) %>%
  spread(Destination, Total.Passengers)

DF

          Origin  ASIA SOUTH AMERICA WESTERN EUROPE
          (fctr) (dbl)         (dbl)          (dbl)
1     EAST AFRICA    NA         10000           4120
2 SOUTHERN AFRICA   200          5000             NA
3     WEST AFRICA   200            NA             NA
```

Comment: Hi @Bryan, indeed, I am working on a dataframe. However, I am not sure why we would need an index column. I tried with it and your code on my data and I got that error :

Comment: Error in utils::getS3method("as_data_frame", "matrix", envir = asNamespace("tibble")) : 
  unused argument (envir = asNamespace("tibble"))

Comment: The index is needed because (referring to the example data `data3`) columns 1, 6 and 7 all have East Africa as the Origin.Destination and Western Europe as the Destination.Region. There is nothing to distinguish these rows other than Total.Passengers. Since that column is being used to `spread`, it becomes ambiguous. For example, for East Africa to Western Europe, which value should it use? 100, 20 or 4000?

Comment: Hi Bryan, this is exactly the result I am hoping and thank you for the explanation. But I still got that error with (envir = asNamespace("tibble")). I copied pasted your code and got the error, so I guess the problem comes from somewhere in my software.. I installed the `tibble` library and played with the different type of data frame, but still can't resolve it though.
What do you mean checking the edit? I am quite beginning with R and still have a lot of things to learn! Thank you,

Comment: By check the edit I just meant check what I added to my original post. Does my code work with the sample data set `data3` that is created in my answer? Does you work require the `tibble` package? If not, try to run the code on a `base data.frame` in a fresh (restarted) environment.

Comment: Oh yes, I did revise your post and recreated it in my R Script. But the error about `tibble` is still there haunting me... I tried the code on my whole dataset and the error is also there.

Comment: @CatherineGladu I had this error with the newest tidyr until I updated to R 3.3.0.  Looks like a compatibility fix [will be forthcoming](https://github.com/hadley/tidyr/issues/202).

Comment: I am on R 3.2.4 and just to see what happens I downloaded `tibble 1.0`. And I am getting no errors. You can try `unloadNamespace("tibble")` to "unload" `tibble` and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Bryan, however I have updated for R 3.3.0 and everything works absolutely perfectly now! Thank you for the info @aeosmith!